# Injective functions between sets

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Given the statement: 
The number of injective functions $f:\{1,2,3,4\} \to \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $\{1,2,3\} \subseteq f[\{1,2,3,4\}]$ **equals** to the number of The number of injective functions $f:\{1,2,3,4\} \to \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $\{1,2\} \not\subseteq f[\{1,2,3,4\}]$

**My question is:**
The statement is true or false?

> MY APPROACH:
>  First, I calculated the number of injective
> functions such that $\{1,2,3\} \subseteq f[\{1,2,3,4\}]$ and I got
> $3! \cdot 5=30$ 
> Second, I calculated the number of all functions
> available from $A$ to $B$: $f:\{1,2,3,4\} \to \{1,2,3,4,5\}$,
> means: $5^4=625$ and then reduced the number of injective functions that do exist $\{1,2\} \subseteq f[\{1,2,3,4\}]: 2 \cdot 5= 50$ and then
> I got: 
>  $625-50 \neq 30$

But I think I have a mistake in my method
any help?

Comment: I think your first calculation is wrong. You have 48 options. As $f$ is injective, you have to choose from $\{f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)\}$ three positions which would be the set $\{1,2,3\}$. You have then $\binom{4}{3}$ options. Now, for each of this options, you have $3!$ ways of filling them with the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$. And lastly, when fixed the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ as image by $f$ of some 3 elements, you still have 2 options for the last one. Total: $2 \binom{4}{3} 3! = 48$.

Comment: And, by the same calculation check your second asertion, and look at the total number of injective functions, not the total number of functions from $A$ to $B$ as you stated.

Comment: Ok, so the be clear, for the second one it will be:  ${4\choose 2}$$\cdot$$2!$$\cdot$$3^2$? and the reduce it from the Universal case of injective functions?

Comment: It's not $3^2$ in your last expression, it is $3!$, it is the same mistake as before. Observe that once you've fixed $1$ and $2$ as image by $f$ of some values from $\{1,2,3,4\}$, suppose we are on the case where $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$, then you have to assign the values for $3$ and $4$, and if you want $f$ to be injective, you only have $3!$ options, because $f(3)$ must be different from $f(4)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eparoh pointed out in the comments, neither of your calculations is correct.

*The number of injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ such that $\{1, 2, 3\} \subseteq f[\{1, 2, 3, 4\}]$*:  The statement means that the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is in the range of the injective function $f$.  There are four ways to select which element of the domain maps to $1$, three ways to select which of the remaining elements in the domain maps to $2$, and two ways to select which of the remaining elements in the domain maps to $3$.  Since the function is injective, the remaining element in the domain must map to $4$ or $5$.  Hence, there are
$$4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 48$$
injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ such that $\{1, 2, 3\} \subseteq f[\{1, 2, 3, 4\}]$.

*The number of injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ such that $\{1, 2\} \not\subseteq f[\{1, 2, 3, 4\}]$*:  The statement means that the elements $1, 2$ cannot both appear in the range of the injective function.  Since the function is injective, each of the four elements in the domain must map to a different element in the codomain, so the range of $f$ must include four of the five elements in the codomain.  Therefore, we can find the number of injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ such that $\{1, 2\} \not\subseteq f[\{1, 2, 3, 4\}]$ by finding the number of injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ that exclude $1$ or exclude $2$.

The number of injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ that exclude $1$ from the range:  There are four ways to select which element of the domain maps to $2$, three ways to select which element of the domain maps to $3$, two ways to select which element of the domain maps to $4$, and one way to select which element of the domain maps to $5$.  Hence, there are
$$4! = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 24$$
injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ which exclude $1$ from the range.

The number of injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ that exclude $2$ from the range:  By symmetry, there are
$$4! = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 24$$
injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ which exclude $2$ from the range.

Since an injective function $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ must have four elements in its range, it is not possible for both $1$ and $2$ to be excluded from the range.  Hence, the number of injective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ such that $\{1, 2\} \not\subseteq f[\{1, 2, 3, 4\}]$ is
$$2 \cdot 4! = 48$$

Comment: Just to point it out, your approach of finding all the injective functions from $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ to $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and substracting the ones such that $\{1, 2\} \subseteq f[\{1, 2, 3, 4\}]$ also works. You can calculate that there are $5!$ different injective functions and $3 \cdot 4!$ such that $\{1, 2\}$ is contained in the range, so the difference is $$5! - 3 \cdot 4! = 5 \cdot 4! - 3 \cdot 4! = 2 \cdot 4!$$ as N. F. Taussig calculated.